# Optimizing Multi-Tenant Database Connections in TypeORM with Custom PostgreSQL Handling

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi-tenant application using TypeORM with PostgreSQL. The common approach of creating a separate DataSource for each tenant leads to inefficient database connection handling. This is because TypeORM's `PostgresDriver` creates a new connection pool each time a new DataSource is initialized. However, it's important to note that the pool itself does not manage the schema; this is handled by either the DataSource or the `PostgresDriver`, but never by the pool. I'm contemplating an alternative approach and would appreciate your insights.

**Problem:**
The standard practice of using a new DataSource for each tenant, while ensuring schema isolation, results in a high number of database connections, particularly under heavy load. This poses scalability challenges.

**Proposed Solution:**
I propose using a "Custom PG version" approach. The idea is to override the pool creation logic in TypeORM's `PostgresDriver` to reuse a single connection pool across multiple tenant requests, thereby reducing the total number of connections.

**Implementation:**

1. **Global Pool Cache:** A cache to store pool instances.
2. **PoolBuilder Function:** A function to check the cache for an existing pool based on connection options, reusing it if available, or creating a new one otherwise.
3. **Custom PG Version:** Modifying the PostgreSQL driver to use `PoolBuilder` instead of the standard pool constructor.

**Code Example:**

```
const cache: { [key: string]: pg.Pool } = {};

function PoolBuilder(this: any, connectionOptions: any) {
  this.key = JSON.stringify(connectionOptions);
  if (!cache[this.key]) {
    cache[this.key] = new pg.Pool({ ...connectionOptions });
  }
  return cache[this.key];
}

const PG = { ...pg, Pool: PoolBuilder };

export const createSchemaDataSource = async (schema: string) => {
  const options = {
    ...ormconfig,
    schema,
    driver: PG,
  };
  const dataSource = new DataSource(options);
  return await dataSource.initialize();
};
```

**Conclusion:**
This approach is aimed at significantly reducing the number of open connections in a multi-tenant environment. However, I'm seeking feedback on potential risks or overlooked aspects of this strategy. The provided code is an example, and I am considering further enhancements, such as distributing connections across multiple pools to prevent system-wide failures.

**Are there any better alternatives or potential issues with handling this scenario? Your insights and suggestions would be highly valuable.**

Thank you in advance for your help!